# QC: Get folder structure with test set and cases along with their pass or fail status

Tags: sql, hp-quality-center

I need some directions on how to approach this...

I have a folder structure in QC like the one I attached in this screenshot: [image]

I want the result in below format

[image]

All along I have been using the cross filter in standard report using Test Instance type. I was able to get the TestSetName, Test cases, Pass or Fail and the custom JIRA Defect ID field but I do not know how to get the folder structure there.

Can anyone give me any directions, please?

Comment: You could use the Open Test API (OTA) to extract the data and format just the way you want. If that's an approach you can take, let me know and I can provide further guidance.

Comment: Hi, I know OTA. I have explored it at a very basic level. Please provide further inputs on how to approach this with OTA. Thank you!

Comment: Use the TDConnection.TestSetTreeManager to get access to the test set tree. From the Root objet you can use NewList to get the child TestSetFolder objects. From each folder you use the TestSetFactory to access the test sets and from each test set use TSTestFactory to get the test case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a little program to export the test hierarchy as a CSV file including an optional list of TSTest values. You can get the code from: https://github.com/thearttrooper/ota.git. The program accounts for hierarchies where the TSTest leaves are not all at the same depth. It'll pad shallow hierarchies so that the leaf values all start in the right place. When exporting a TSTest property, you specify the user label of the property, not the DB column name. For example you use "Status", not TS_STATUS.